# How to align li::marker of an ordered list and dt element of a description list nested in that ordered list in Reveal.js produced with R Markdown?

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, reveal.js

I nested a descliption list into an ordered list, and am trying to align `li::marker` of the ordered list and `dt` element of the description list. However, as shown in the figure on the following URL, `li::marker` and the contents of the nested description list are bottom-aligned. Then, how can I top-align both of them?

[image]

## MWE

````
---
author: CLRR
date: | 
  | Last Update: `r format(Sys.time(), '%Y/%m/%d')`）
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    self_contained: false
    reveal_plugins: ["notes", "search"]
    transition: slide
    pandoc_args:
      - --wrap=preserve
---

1. Item A
  ~ This is A!
  ~ It's good!
1. Item B
  ~ This is B!
  ~ It's new!

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.reveal h1,
.reveal h2,
.reveal h3,
.reveal h4,
.reveal h5,
.reveal h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

.reveal h1,
.reveal h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.reveal code{
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  margin: 2px 2px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 24pt;
  */
}

.reveal pre {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 24pt;
  line-height: ;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  */
}

.reveal  pre code {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  */
}

.reveal .slide {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

/*
12pt

|name          |    pt| relative_size|
|:-------------|-----:|-------------:|
|\tiny         |  6.00|      50.00000|
|\scriptsize   |  8.00|      66.66667|
|\footnotesize | 10.00|      83.33333|
|\small        | 10.95|      91.25000|
|\normalsize   | 12.00|     100.00000|
|\large        | 14.40|     120.00000|
|\Large        | 17.28|     144.00000|
|\LARGE        | 20.74|     172.83333|
|\huge         | 24.88|     207.33333|
|\Huge         | 24.88|     207.33333|

*/

.reveal .footer {
  font-size: 83%;
}

.columns {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  /* word-break: break-all; */
  /* display: inline-flex; */
  /* flex: auto; */
}

.uri {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.reveal .speaker-controls {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}
/* 
#vcenter {
  vertical-align: middle;
} */
```

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
</style>
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be removing the list marker and adding css counters to `dt` elements.

````
---
author: CLRR
date: | 
  | Last Update: `r format(Sys.time(), '%Y/%m/%d')`）
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    self_contained: false
    reveal_plugins: ["notes", "search"]
    transition: slide
    pandoc_args:
      - --wrap=preserve
---


1. Item A
  ~ This is A!
  ~ It's good!
1. Item B
  ~ This is B!
  ~ It's new!
1. Item C
  ~ This is C!
  ~ It's popular!!

```{css, echo=FALSE}

/* Adding CSS counter to dt elements nested in li ------------------------ */

.reveal li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.reveal ol {
  counter-reset: css-counter 0;
}

.reveal li dt {
  counter-increment: css-counter 1;
}

.reveal li dt:before {
  content: counter(css-counter) ". ";
  width: 1rem;
}

.reveal li dd {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

/* Done adding CSS counter to dt elements nested in li -------------------- */

.reveal h1,
.reveal h2,
.reveal h3,
.reveal h4,
.reveal h5,
.reveal h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

.reveal h1,
.reveal h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.reveal code{
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  margin: 2px 2px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 24pt;
  */
}

.reveal pre {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 24pt;
  line-height: ;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  */
}

.reveal  pre code {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  /*
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  */
}

.reveal .slide {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

/*
12pt

|name          |    pt| relative_size|
|:-------------|-----:|-------------:|
|\tiny         |  6.00|      50.00000|
|\scriptsize   |  8.00|      66.66667|
|\footnotesize | 10.00|      83.33333|
|\small        | 10.95|      91.25000|
|\normalsize   | 12.00|     100.00000|
|\large        | 14.40|     120.00000|
|\Large        | 17.28|     144.00000|
|\LARGE        | 20.74|     172.83333|
|\huge         | 24.88|     207.33333|
|\Huge         | 24.88|     207.33333|

*/

.reveal .footer {
  font-size: 83%;
}

.columns {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  /* word-break: break-all; */
  /* display: inline-flex; */
  /* flex: auto; */
}

.uri {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.reveal .speaker-controls {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}
/* 
#vcenter {
  vertical-align: middle;
} */
```

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
</style>
````

---

[image: nested dt elements in the list]

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your code works well but `.reveal li { list-style-type: none; }` makes the numbers of other ordered lists invisible. Would you mind answereing 
[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74077697/10215301) regarding that point, if you are interested in it?